# Why won't the Linux wall command broadcast a string argument?

Tags: linux, command-line

I read [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/opensource/send-messages-and-alerts-from-the-command-line/262) that this should work, but it doesn't:

```
# usage: wall [file]
root@sys:~> mesg
is y

root@sys:~> wall "who's out there"
wall: can't read who's out there.
```

If `mesg` is set to `y`, what's preventing me from broadcasting a string? Note, I did confirm that the *file* option works:

```
root@sys:~> wall test
Broadcast Message from root@sys (/dev/pts/1) at 15:23 ... 
Who's out there?
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem lies in the syntax used in the linked article. To understand what exactly goes wrong, let's have a look at `man wall`:

Usage from `man wall`:

```
wall [file]

Wall displays the contents of file or, by default, its standard input
```

So `wall` accepts *either* of two sources for its message.

### File name argument

Any command line argument given to `wall` has to be a file name. As there isn't a reliable way to tell if the argument is meant as message or file name, `wall` will assume it's the latter, ignore anything coming in on [standard input](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_input#Standard_input_.28stdin.29), and try to read the message from that file.

In the given case, it tries to read from the file `who's out there` and does not find it. Note that reading from a file is usually restricted to the superuser. If you'd executed `wall "who's out there"` as an unprivileged user, likely its output would have been, `wall: will not read who's out there - use stdin.`

### Standard input

If it doesn't get a file name argument on its command line, it will start reading from standard input. There are several ways to feed information to the standard input of a command. One is to use a [UNIX pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)). A pipeline will connect the standard output of its lefthand-side command to the standard input of its righthand-side command:

```
$ echo "who's out there" | wall
```

Another way is to use a [here document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document). A `here document` is a shell construct that passes a string (up to a specified end marker on a line of its own) directly to the standard input of a command, without the intermediate step of having a distinct command produce that output:

```
$ wall << .
who's out there?
.
```

This would be a "useless use of here documents", because by default the terminal itself will be connected to `wall`'s standard input and `wall` will start reading from it until it receives an end-of-file character (<kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>):

```
$ wall
who's out there?
^D
```

As [Rich Homolka](https://superuser.com/users/8804/) noted in the comments, some shells support `here strings` which allow passing a literal string without command or end markers:

```
$ wall <<< "who's out there?"
```

All feed something to `wall`'s standard input. The difference is that a pipeline connects the output of another command to it, while `here documents` and `here strings` pass the string directly. The latter two's advantage here is an aesthetic one, as the `echo` command from the pipe example is a shell built-in command, so it will be the shell providing `wall`'s input in all cases.

Comment: Bash/zsh has another format to avoid the `echo xxx | yyy` syntax, which I find cludgy
`wall <<<'your message'`

Comment: I'm not sure about that one Rich - the syntax of wall shouldn't be based off the shell unless there's a .bashrc or whatever the zsh equivalent is. I use bash too.

Comment: Thank you peth - that's the syntactical organization I needed to learn!

Comment: My mistake Rich! With Peth's clarification I now see that you were offering the `wall <<< string` sintax. That's pretty great. Can either of you explain what `<<<` is doing exactly (and why it would be more efficient as peth said)? I find it odd that a cmd that requires a file can accept a string after `<<<`. Thanks again.

Comment: @mjb It's actually unlikely that the herestring is more efficient than echo - herestrings work by making a temporary file, and then attaching that as a process's stdin (file descriptor 0), which is why `wall` accepts it (wall reads from stdin if you don't specify a file). As a way of verifying that herestrings create a file, `$ readlink /proc/self/fd/0 <<< test` will print something like `/tmp/sh-thd-4228536315 (deleted)`.

Answer (score 0):

try with root

```
root@username:~# wall /home/username/yourfile_name
```

if your file is in home directory otherwise try another path